# Can I not display a push notification once it has reached a device?

Tags: android, push-notification

Is it possible to not display a push notification after the phone has actually received it?

I'm building a chatting application. Push notifications are sent every time a message is sent to user X. If user X is inside the `Activity` that represents the chat with user Y, and receives a message from user Y, I would like the push notification to not display.

Is this possible with regular GCM push notifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it only with `IntentService`.

When a new `Notification` is received in your `BroadcastReceiver`, you will send it to the `IntentService` so, there before displaying Notification with `NotificationBuilder` have a `Listener` set to the `Activity`. If `Listener` exists, the user is inside the Activity, then just ignore the notifications.

For Example, define a Listener like this,

```
 public interface PushNotificationListenerService {
    public void showNewMessage();
}
```

And in your `IntentService` before displaying Notification,

```
 public void setListener(PushNotificationListenerService listener) {
    onPushReceivedCallback = listener;
 }

 Handler mHandler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (onPushReceivedCallback != null) {      
              onPushReceivedCallback.showNewMessage();
              // then ignore the notification.
            }
                            else{
              // show notification
        }
    });
```

In you Activity,

`onCreate` Method,

```
 NotificationIntentService.getInstance(this).setListener(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

The messages received through `GCM` are processed by your `IntentService` which will be triggered each time a new message is received, but it's completely up to you what do you do with that message.

If you plan to act in base of an active/inactive `Activity`, I'd suggest declaring a global `boolean` that will be true when `onCreate()` or `onResume()` is called, and set to false when `onDestroy()` or `onPause()` are called. So if you receive a message, you see what value it has and act accordingly to its current state.